# Parallel Stochastic Gradient Descent

Tags: regression, optimization, gradient-descent

I am trying to solve a linear regression problem with multiple variables in a Hadoop cluster. I was thinking of using SGD to estimate the parameters, but there is one issue I don't know how to solve. The SGD is calculated in parallel through all the nodes of the cluster, and my question is how to combine the output of those nodes. I mean, if I have for example a data set of 1000 rows and 5 nodes estimating the parameters using SGD with 200 rows of the data set each of them, how would I combine in a last step those 5 outputs?

Comment: Hi Balduz, do you use OLS to fit each of the linear models?

Comment: Yes, I am using OLS

Comment: What about just averaging the estimates obtained from each node?

Comment: That alone would give a good result? That is what I was considering but I thought that perhaps it was too simple and that I would need to do something else, like using batch GD instead, but that would be the worst option since I would need to iterate many times through a huge dataset

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I think that if you have a big dataset you should get a reasonable result. Do the estimates differ by a lot between nodes? I am confused about one point: you are using OLS with a linear model and that has a closed form solution so why should you do many iterations of batch GD?

Comment: I don't know if the estimates differ by a lot since I still haven't tried it out, I'm working on the theory before coding it since I still don't have the cluster. If I use batch GD, the parameters won't be updated until it has finished reading the whole dataset. Therefore, I would need to run several mapreduce jobs, however if I use SGD I could get the parameters in a single run